# I am not getting desired output

Tags: python

```
import random
num = random.randint(1,10)
guess = 0
guess_count = 0
out_of_guess = False
print(num)
while guess!=num and not (out_of_guess):
    if guess_count<3:
        guess = input("Enter a guess : ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guess = True

if out_of_guess:
    print("You Lose!")
else:
    print("You Win")
```

Note: I wrote print(num) so that I can see if the program is working or not.

The program always prints out you lose even when I type in the right number. I get 3 chances as programmed but it does not stop after I type the correct number, say, on the second try. I can't figure what is going wrong in this program.

Comment: `input` returns a string, and testing for equality between a string and an integer will always return `False`. You have to turn the user's input into an integer.

Comment: Try: `guess = int(input("Enter a guess : "))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are comparing an input that is an `str` to `num` that it's `int` you can cast the input to `int` by that the `guess!=num` the statement will return True in case of the input number is equal to the `num`.

```
import random
num = random.randint(1,10)
guess = 0
guess_count = 0
out_of_guess = False
print(num)
while guess!=num and not (out_of_guess):
    if guess_count<3:
        guess = input("Enter a guess : ")
        guess = int(guess) if guess.isdigit() else guess
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guess = True

if out_of_guess:
    print("You Lose!")
else:
    print("You Win")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the type of the obects. the function randint give you a integer, while the input that you get is a string. So you have to cast the integer to string or the string to integer to fix the issue

```
import random
num = random.randint(1,10)
guess = 0
guess_count = 0
out_of_guess = False
print(num)
while guess!=str(num) and not (out_of_guess):
    if guess_count<3:
        guess = input("Enter a guess : ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guess = True

if out_of_guess:
    print("You Lose!")
else:
    print("You Win")
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to compare guess into an integer.

Just try:

```
while int(guess) != num and not out_of_guess:
    ...
```

Of course, if you input a letter, it will raise an error. It's up to you to figure out how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

the method `input` return a string object and you need to convert it to integer. using the `int(str)` method. you can enclouse it with `try except` block for manipulating wrong user inputs (not numbers). see below:

```
import random
num = random.randint(1,10)
guess = 0
guess_count = 0
out_of_guess = False
print(num)
while guess!=num and not out_of_guess:
    if guess_count<3:
        try:    
            guess = int(input("Enter a guess : "))
            guess_count += 1
        except ValueError:
            print("Only numbers is allowed ! try again!")
    else:
        out_of_guess = True

if out_of_guess:
    print("You Lose!")
else:
    print("You Win")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think, this might be the way you are looking for:

```
import random

secret_num = random.randint(1,10)
guess = 0

print("Secret Number: "+ str(secret_num))

for i in range(3): # 3 chances
    guess = eval(input("Enter a guess: ")) #get input
    if(guess == secret_num): #if guess is right, break
        break

if(guess==secret_num):
    print("You won")
else:
    print("You lose")
```

- Less lines of code
- Less variables
- Easy to understand & read

Hope it helps :)